# Why isn't the interface member mapped to the non-static method of the derived class

Tags: c#

I write a interface and a base class `A` implementing it, and then a derived class `B`:

```
interface ITest
{
    void fn();
}

class A: ITest
{ 

    void ITest.fn()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("fn in A");
    }
}

class B: A
{

    public void fn()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("fn in B");
    }

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ITest tan = new B();
        tan.fn();
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

The result shows that the `fn` in `A` is called. But according to the [interface mapping rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664592(v=vs.71).aspx), I am quite puzzled:

> 1. If S contains a declaration of an explicit interface member
>      implementation that matches I and M, then this member is the
>      implementation of I.M.
> 2. Otherwise, if S contains a declaration of a
>      non-static public member that matches M, then this member is the
>      implementation of I.M.

For an instance of `B`, it doesn't match the rule 1, there is no explicit interface member implementation. 
However, it has its own non-static public member `fn`, which I think matchs the rule 2. So the `tan.fn()` should call the method `fn` of `B`, there is no need to look for another `fn` in its base class `A`.

What is wrong?

(Solving this problem will help me understand interface reimplemention)

Answer (score 1):

Because it is an explicit interface implementation. Implementing the interface implicitly makes the method visible in B as well.

Furthermore, to be able to override it in B, you need to make it virtual.

Rule 2 does not apply to B, because Rule 1 does. There is an explicit interface implementation, i.e. the one inherited from A.

Change your code as follows:

```
class A : ITest
{ 
    public virtual void fn()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("fn in A");
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public override void fn()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("fn in B");
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you do want to implement the interface explicitly, you can have the implementation call a protected virtual method that you can override in B.

```
class A : ITest
{ 
    void ITest.fn()
    {
        FnCore();
    }

    protected virtual void FnCore()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("fn in A");
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public override void FnCore()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("fn in B");
    }
}
```

As Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov points out, you can also reimplement the interface, by changing the declaration of B as follows:

```
class B : A, ITest
```

However, that has one big disadvantage: the method is not polymorphic in the way you would usually expect. Indeed, this code would give you the result you expect:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ITest tan = new B();
    tan.fn();
}
```

Given your interface is implemented explicitly in A, the code below doesn't compile. But if it were implemented implicitly, the code below would still output "fn in A" when B merely reimplements the interface without overriding the virtual base method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    A tan = new B();
    tan.fn();
}
```

Comment: You do not re-implement interface, you override a method that just happens to be a part of an interface. You can re-implement interface without virtual methods: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664594(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov Indeed. I have updated my answer to mention that fact, but also pointed out the disadvantage.

Comment: Thank you, I've mentioned it only for the sake of correctness as I see it. Re-implementing is a rare scenario imho (I used it only once in producion code).

Comment: But if I change the declaration of `B` as `class B : A, ITest`, it doesn't change that `B` implements the interface explicitly, the one inherited from `A`. So Rule 1 still applies and `fn` in `A` should be called?

Comment: @ClaudeTan no. When you're re-implementing the interface it's not about mapping.
`public class A : II
{
     void II.f(){ Console.WriteLine("A"); }
 }
public class B : A, II
{
    void II.f() { Console.WriteLine("B"); }
}II AasII = new A();
. II BasII = new B();
> A BasA = new A();
> AasII.f();
. BasII.f();`
It writes
`A B`

Comment: @ClaudeTan I guess that you're confused because 1) you are mixing the interface implementation with class inheritance while they are different mechanisms and 2) mapping is a rule for how implementation should be described, it does not describe how implemented interfaces are called.

Comment: @ClaudeTan no offense, it was only a guess and I though it would be good to point it out.

Comment: You are right, actually I regard interface as a special kind of base types in inheritance, which doesn't make sense here.@Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's some code with intermediate language it does produce and comments:

```
public interface II
    {
        void f();
    }

    #region Explicit
    public class AExplicit : II
    {
        void II.f() => Console.WriteLine(nameof(AExplicit));
    }  

    public class BExplicitIndependent : AExplicit
    {
        // void II.f() => Console.WriteLine("BExplicit"); // won't compile
        // f() does not hide anything - it's completely new method
        public void f() => Console.WriteLine("B that defines an independent method void f()");
    }

    public class BExplicitReImplemented : AExplicit, II
    {
        void II.f() => Console.WriteLine(nameof(BExplicitReImplemented));
    }
    #endregion Explicit

    #region Implicit
    public class AImplicit : II
    {
        public void f() => Console.WriteLine(nameof(AImplicit));
    }


    public class BImplicitIndependent : AImplicit
    {
        // WARNING: BImplicitReImplemented.f()' hides inherited member 'AImplicit.f()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
        public void f() => Console.WriteLine("B that defines an independent method void f()");
    }

    public class BImplicitReImplemented : AImplicit, II
    {
        public void f() => Console.WriteLine(nameof(BImplicitReImplemented));
    }

    #endregion Implicit

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            II AEasII = new AExplicit();
            II BEIndependentasII = new BExplicitIndependent();
            II BEasII = new BExplicitReImplemented();
            AExplicit BEIndependentasAE = new BExplicitIndependent();
            BExplicitIndependent BExplicitIndependentAsItself = new BExplicitIndependent();

            AEasII.f(); // IL: callvirt instance void xxx.II::f()
            BEIndependentasII.f(); // IL: callvirt instance void xxx.II::f()
            BEasII.f(); // IL: callvirt instance void xxx.II::f()
            // BEIndependentasAE.f(); no such method in A
            BExplicitIndependentAsItself.f(); // new method IL: callvirt instance void xxx.BExplicitIndependent::f()

            II AIasII = new AImplicit();
            II BIIndependentasII = new BImplicitIndependent();
            II BIasII = new BImplicitReImplemented();
            AImplicit BIIndependentAsAI = new BImplicitIndependent();
            BImplicitIndependent BIIndependentAsItself = new BImplicitIndependent();

            AIasII.f(); // IL: callvirt instance void xxx.II::f()
            BIIndependentasII.f(); // IL: callvirt instance void xxx.II::f()
            BIasII.f(); // IL: callvirt instance void xxx.II::f()
            BIIndependentAsAI.f(); // A method, but it has nothing to do with interfaces // IL: callvirt instance void xxx.AImplicit::f()
            BIIndependentAsItself.f(); // B method, but it also has nothing to do with interfaces // IL: callvirt instance void xxx.BImplicitIndependent::f()
        }
    }
```

As far as I understand, the mapping rule describes how method implementation is picked from your code, it does not describe how to pick anything at runtime. The one and only implementation (for any particular call) is being called. If you want, you can compile the code above (as a console application and inspect all produced IL yourself).